# How to convert this '\x5b\x5b\x5b' to this '[[['

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

It's easy in JavaScript, but how to convert in PQ?
Is there an easy way?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should explain hat we are looking at? I haven't the faintest idea.. I did find something about x5b deer hunting, but I don't think that would be relevant in this context.

Comment: More context is definitely required. Where is this happening? How is this related to Power Query or Power BI?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in JavaScript source code, `'\x5b\x5b\x5b\x220BwP4bPODhDZVZzVcXdmZlVnenc\x22'` compiles to the same value as `'[[["0BwP4bPODhDZVZzVcXdmZlVnenc"'` so there is no conversion.

JavaScript strings are counted sequences of UTF-16 code units. UTF-16 is an encoding for the Unicode Character set. A JavaScript literal string allows several types of escape sequences. One is \xHH, where HH is the hexadecimal number (0 to 255) for an ISO 8859-1 code unit. ISO 8859-1 is a subset of Unicode and has the same codepoints as the first 256 Unicode codepoints. UTF-16 encodes those codepoints to the same values.

Power Query strings are also counted sequences of UTF-16 code units. (As are strings in Java, C#, VB4/5/6, VBA, VBScript, VB, F#, …, for that matter.) So, your string is almost there, except for the escapes. We can convert the JavaScript literal string to a Power Query text value in a few steps.

JavaScript also has \uHHHH escapes, where HHHH is the hexadecimal number for a UTF-16 code unit.  Because of the similarity between Unicode and ISO 8859-1, \xHH is effectively shorthand for \u00HH.

JSON simplifies JavaScript literal strings, allowing \uHHHH escapes but not \xHH. Power Query has data transformation functions for JSON. So, we need to convert JavaScript to JSON and then transform.

In a blank query, open the Advanced Editor and paste:

```
let
    JavaScriptLiteral = "\x5b\x5b\x5b\x220BwP4bPODhDZVZzVcXdmZlVnenc\x22",
    JsonLiteral = """" & Text.Replace(JavaScriptLiteral, "\x","\u00") & """",
    Value = Json.Document(JsonLiteral)
in
    Value
```

(This will break if given a source with other escapes like `"\\x"` or with double quotes.)

You, can, of course, turn this into a Power Query function if you need to apply it to more than one string, or you can convert it to a table, or ….

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, specific to your \x5b\x5b\x5b portion.

If you start with a table named Table1 as your source for your Power Query query, with your text in Column1:

[image]

Then Transform -> Replace Values, using these settings:

[image]

...to get this:

[image]

You can then Add Column -> Custom Column with this:

[image]

... to get this:

[image]

Then you can extract the values in the new Custom column:

[image]

... to get this:

[image]